# What happened to Naruto's Six Paths Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

In *The Last: Naruto the Movie*,

> Naruto appears fighting Toneri using Tailed Beast Mode with Sage Mode. What happened to his stronger form (Six Paths Sage Mode)!? Did he lose it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a theory that Naruto still has the potential to use it but he doesn't, since it needs chakra from all nine Tailed Beasts, which he used up in his battle against Sasuke. The sage said that he was a pseudo-Ten Tails and that the Tailed Beasts could all go into him to speak with each other (this was after he took back his yin and yang seals from Naruto and Sasuke). He may have felt there was no need to, since both halves of the Kyuubi are sealed inside him now.

Comment: Maybe, but i still believe six paths sage mode is stronger than full nine tails mode since its the chakra from all tailed beasts, and from the few videos i saw of the movies it appears that he had some difficult dealing with toneri in nine tails mode... and i know for sure that six paths sage mode doesn't appear in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Even If he doesn't have all the tailed beast he still should have half of the sages chakra but he did lose the are in which the sage gave his chakra. The movie didn't really show Naruto going all out from what I've seen. 
I don't even know if Naruto still have the truth seeking balls.

Answer (score 0):

The Six Paths Sage Mode is a heightened state of Sage Mode, which drastically empowers the user's abilities to a far greater extent by combining the **Six Paths Sage Chakra** and the **chakra of all nine Tailed Beasts**. Hagaromo takes back his Yang chakra from Naruto, thus taking away the Six Paths Sage Chakra. I think this might have led to Naruto losing the Six Paths Sage Mode. Maybe...

Comment: I see your point of view, but sasuke awakens his rinnegan with six paths chakra too. In the movie he appears with the rinnegan, it doesn't seem fair that sasuke keeps his power-up and naruto loses six paths sage mode. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that he still has access to the Six Paths Sage Mode, due to the fact that he could still enter it during his fight with Sasuke even after the mark on his hand vanished. Plus, even after the battle with Sasuke, it is shown that he was able to dispel the Infinite Tsukiyomi with Sasuke, which requires both the Rinnegan and the power of all Tailed Beasts according to the sage.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that how Minato sealed part of Kurama, in which it could repllenish its own energy when its low. I'm guessing that the taled beast within Naruto could do the samething. Seeing as Hagoromo said that Naruto would be the meeting place for all the tailed beast.

Naruto should have the potential to use six paths sage mode, seeing as Sasuke still has full access of his rinnegan. He could even turn the eye off completly. I remember reading somewhere that in the Last movie Naruto's chakra was turned into a bomb that destroyed half the moon. That could be why he doesn't use that mode. I did see that Naruto could touch Toneri Ōtsutsuki's truth seeking balls which means he has the other half of Hagoromo's chakra which is the important thing.

Answer (score -2):

Sage mode is all about natural energy and the moon has no nature, so Naruto can't connect with all the Tailed Beasts. That's why he can't go into the Six Paths Sage Mode. Six Paths Sage Mode is a heightened state of Sage Mode. If Naruto can't use Sage Mode on the moon, he also can't use Six Paths Sage Mode because of the absence of nature. He can't collect any natural energy and he  also can't connect to other Tailed Beasts because they all are still on Earth.